# How to convert every other character to upper case in a string

Tags: java, type-conversion

I currently have an assignment where we have the entire (swedish) alphabet in lower case as a string, and we should convert every other character to upper case. This is where I am right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö";
    System.out.println(alphabet);
    for (int i = 0; i < 29; i = i + 2) {
        char result = alphabet.charAt(i);
        alphabet.toUpperCase(result);
    }
    System.out.println(alphabet);
}
```

The problem now is that `alphabet.toUpperCase(result);` gives me an error that I can't convert char to locale. How do I fix this?

Comment: Well, have you looked at the documentation for `String.toUpperCase`? Does it take a `char` parameter? If it did, what would you expect calling the method to do, given that you're not using the result anywhere?

Comment: The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase-java.util.Locale-) is your friend.

Comment: If you want to convert a specific *character* to uppercase, the Character class would be a good place to start.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the uppercase of a char, you should use `Character.toUpperCase(c)`, not String's toUpperCase.

So, I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö";
    System.out.println(alphabet);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {
        char c = alphabet.charAt(i);
        sb.append(i % 2 == 0 ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : c);
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö
>
> AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYzÅäÖ

Since Strings are immutable, you have to create a new String to get what you want. An efficient way of doing this is with a StringBuilder.

**Edit:**

Another way to do it without StringBuilder and perhaps a more intuitive way is to convert the String to an array of chars, which makes it mutable. In the end, you just convert it back to a String. The result would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö";
    System.out.println(alphabet);

    char[] chars = alphabet.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i+=2) {
        chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
    }
    String result = new String(chars);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: The problem is he is trying to do an toUpperCase on the string with a char and that is not how  that method works. I believed I somehow say this with the first line in my answer.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Im not sure that my teacher wants me to use StringBuilder, but it will have to do.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked it since your example is that much different then hers...

Comment: I added an example that doesn't use StringBuilder that might be more intuitive.